# Why does the alignas specifier throw an error on Clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

According to the standard, the `new` expression's grammar allows the `alignas` specifier along with other attribute specifiers to be supplied. I have seen other code using this but GCC ignores the attribute specifier, even if it is within the max alignment, and Clang throws an error.

- Is the `alignas` specifier actually valid within a `new` expression?
- If it is valid, why does Clang reject my code and why does GCC ignore my attribute no matter what alignment I request?

I am not trying to solve a specific problem, I am just trying to understand the standard.

```cpp
    int* example = new alignas(16) int[2];
    // alignof(std::max_align_t) = 16
    // sizeof(int) = 4, sizeof(example) = 8
```

GCC:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:7:41: warning: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
    7 |     int* example = new alignas(16) int[2];
      |                                         ^
prog.cc:7:41: note: an attribute that appertains to a type-specifier is ignored
```

Clang:

```
 prog.cc:7:24: error: an attribute list cannot appear here:
               int* example = new alignas(16) int[2];
```

Reproducible on latest GCC and Clang, example: http://cpp.sh/3hfl7

References:

http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#nt:new-expression

```
new-type-id:
    type-specifier-seq new-declarator opt

type-specifier-seq:
    type-specifier attribute-specifier-seq opt
    type-specifier type-specifier-seq
```

(new-type-id -> type-specifier-seq -> attribute-specifier-seq -> attribute-specifier -> alignment-specifier is permitted by grammar)

`attribute-specifier-seq` can include an alignment specifier.

Comment: *"According to the standard"* Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Added a reference to what I was looking and confused about. Having a hard time figuring out if the standard allows this, if it's implementation defined, or if it's just undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the grammar you cited states that an *attribute-specifier-seq* that occurs in a *type-specifier-seq* has to occur after all *type-specifiers*. Therefore, you'd have to put it here in order to have the attributes appertain to the preceding `int` according to [[dcl.type]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#1):

```
new int attribute-specifier-seq [2];
```

You'd have to put it here in order to have the attributes appertain to the array type according to [[expr.new]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#6):

```
new int [2] attribute-specifier-seq;
```

You could also combine them: you can have different attributes for the array type and for the element type. But I don't think the grammar allows you to place the attributes before the `int`.

As for the specific issue of an alignment specifier: the standard neither explicitly permits nor explicitly forbids applying an alignment specifier to a *type-specifier* or *type-id* ([[dcl.align]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.align#1)). Clang seems to interpret the standard as forbidding it. GCC seems to interpret the standard as allowing it; however, since the standard does not specify any semantics for the alignment specifier when it appertains to a type, a warning is issued. Consider:

```
struct S {
    int x alignas(16);
    int alignas(16) y;
};
```

Here, `S::x` will have an alignment requirement of 16 but the alignment specifier for `S::y` is meaningless. So if you write `int alignas(16) y`, it makes sense for GCC to warn you so you realize you put it in the wrong place.

To force the allocated memory to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary, use the placement syntax to explicitly call the overload of `operator new` that takes an alignment argument:

```
int* x = new (std::align_val_t(16)) int [2];
```